# Issues while deploying tomcat 7 in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a java Spring application that I want to deploy to Cloudfoundry on Tomcat7. I am newbie to Cloudfoundry and followed the steps mentioned [here](http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/) but when I issue `vmc push` command I am getting warning `Can't determine the Application Type` with no options provided. Any idea to resolve this ?

```
C:\apps\tomcat7>vmc push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]:

Application Name: myApp77

[WARNING] Can't determine the Application Type.

Select Application Type:
```

Answer (score 2):

Dan's comment is correct. You should be given the option to choose standalone app.
You may want to have a look at https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7 which is a distribution of tomcat already customized (and tested) as described in the blog post you mention.

Even better, if you're using Maven, just follow the README and you'll be able to deploy your war project automatically as a tomcat7 standalone.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

This actually sounds correct to me, in the list of application types should be an entry named "standalone application". Select that one and then provide the command you wish to start the application with, in this case it's 'bin/startup.sh'